# Unexpected variable assignment inside static class method

Tags: actionscript-3

Hoping someone can assist with a particularly unusual problem. In the following code (thoroughly debugged) the first case (1) in the switch is met and a new instance of BannerSingle is assigned to retVal (the return value). Unfortunately, while the second case (2) is never met, the assignment therein to retVal takes place and I can't compile. When I comment out the assignment to retVal for "case 2:" everything works fine.

I've tried using an if/else instead and I still get the same odd behavior. Also tried a number of solutions involving separate variables, etc. 
Anyone happen to know where I've messed up? Thanks in advance.
JAP

```
package fl {

import fl.IBanner;
import fl.Banner;
import fl.BannerSingle;
import fl.BannerVars;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class BannerFactory {

    private static var retVal:IBanner;

    public function BannerFactory() {}

    public static function createBanner(bannerVars:Object, ob:Stage):IBanner {          
        switch (bannerVars.numRecipes) {
            case 1:
                retVal = new BannerSingle(bannerVars, ob);
                break;
            case 2:
                retVal = new Banner(bannerVars, ob);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }   
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does Banner implement IBanner?

Comment: Forgot to mention, sorry. Both BannerSingle and Banner implement IBanner. Even if I don't return them (just create new instances locally) the problem persists.

Comment: When you say you can't compile, what is the error given?

Comment: Very odd, they all have to do with missing properties inside the "Banner" class. Which is why when I comment out "retVal = new Banner(..." the errors disappear. Case 2 is never met, however. I can add a trace and it won't appear.

Comment: Does the Banner class implement IBanner correctly (completely)?

Comment: If it helps (to understand my hackery) "ob" is a reference to the main stage. BannerSingle adds content to the display list using that variable. Thought this might be part of the problem.

Comment: All methods and signatures are matching and included--at least as far as the Flash IDE is concerned (it stopped throwing up errors).

Comment: Hmm. It's hard to diagnose with out a look inside IBanner, Banner, and BannerSingle. It appears right now that Banner must do something wrong that BannerSingle does correctly.

Comment: I would suspect that the missing properties are things IBanner defines that don't actually exist on Banner. You may also want to check out the comments here http://www.as3dp.com/2010/10/bend-over-this-wont-hurt-a-bit-actionscript-3-0-dependency-injection/ (particularly by Shaun) on why you might want to give the Factory pattern a pass, especially if you base it on static methods, which you will be unable to switch out for some other creation mechanism in the future.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I regret to have wasted anyone's time but I think my solution is embarrassingly simple. I won't waste more of your time telling you how silly the remedy is.

Answer (score 0):

You should use braces to introduce a new declaration space, without them any variables declared inside the switch statement are visible from their point of declaration throughout all case branches. Try the following.

```
    switch (bannerVars.numRecipes) {
        case 1:
        {
            retVal = new BannerSingle(bannerVars, ob);
        }
            break;
        case 2:
        {
            retVal = new Banner(bannerVars, ob);
        }
            break;
    }
```

Also, the empty default case is redundant...